# Get records for last 2 days

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am trying to create a query to get the records for last two days. In my table there is a field called **dates**. Values are as below:

```
05-08-2018 08:05:22
05-08-2018 10:15:42
```

**dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:ss**

I have created the query.

```
SELECT id,title,description, dates
FROM post_feed where `dates` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY dates DESC LIMIT 100
```

When I run the query it return 0 records. It looks like issue with date format.

Comment: Just store dates properly

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your dates are stored as varchar. You must convert them to date (e.g. by using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)) before you can perform any comparison.

Assuming for example that today is Aug-05 and you want results for Aug-04 and 05 (inclusive):

```
SELECT id, title, description, dates
FROM post_feed
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dates, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY dates DESC
LIMIT 100
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/700703/3)

Comment: Salman how can i get the records for today and yesterday. Please advise.

Comment: The above query should work. Actually it will return rows between last 48 hours. If I understand your problem correctly, change the where clause to WHERE `STR_TO_DATE(dates, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()`.

Comment: @Ironic See revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your second date is before your first date. Put greater date at first place & put lesser date at second place.

```
   SELECT id,title,description, dates
    FROM post_feed where CAST(`dates`as date) BETWEEN  CURDATE() AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    ORDER BY dates DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: you have to cast 'dates' column to "YYYY-MM-DD" format. I have updated my code with typecast

Comment: `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` is ***LESS THAN*** `CURDATE()`

Comment: I want to include current date records and last date recrods.

Comment: absolutely wrong. BETWEEN caluse expects smaller and lager value in that order. And CASTing dates stored in wrong format will simply result in `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dates, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: 0 recrods returning by using your query.

Comment: @Ironic It seems that you have non-standard format of date, thus you need to cast it to proper `datetime` format. Try updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your data!  Your query doesn't work because the "date" value are stored as text/varchar.  This is easily fixed:

```
update post_feed
    set dates = str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

alter table post_feed
    modify column datetime;
```

Voila!  Your queries will now work.